Поломался порядок релизов в Github
Есть проект, сначала был добавлен тег и релиз v.0.8, потом тег и релиз v.0.9, все работало нормально. Потом возникла необходимость добавить теги и релизы для ранних версий. Через git tag -a и git push на гитхаб были выгружены теги старых версий (v.0.1 v.0.2 и т.д.), после чего на сайта к тегами были привязаны релизы. Теперь релизы со старыми новыми тегами отображаются после релизов v.0.8 и v.0.9. Как это починить?

Релизы или теги? На гитхабе это разные вещи

А вообще, может быть, тут что-то толковое написано https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863647

Новые (по времени) релизы отображаются первыми, все так и задумано.

Я запустил эту чудную команду, которая привязывает время создания тега к времени комита и отправляет измененные теги на гитхаб, после чего пересоздал все релизы. Порядок стал нормальным.
git tag -l | while read -r tag ; do COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-list -1 $tag) && GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git show $COMMIT_HASH --format=%aD | head -1)" git tag -a -f $tag -m"$tag" $COMMIT_HASH ; done && git push --tags --force

